# is_superuser flag is not working correctly once loggin and not redirecting to a custom admin dashboard

Tags: python, django, redirect, superuser

Once trying to login to the system with a superuser's credentials it is not working properly and redirecting home page instead of custom admin page. The system is treating both superuser and a normal user equally in views but is_superuser flag is working when I use in templates for ex, showing different links in navbar and I am using signals to create user instance.

Views.py

```
def custom_user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username", "")
        password = request.POST.get("password", "")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("admin_page")
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, "registration/login.html", {"form": form})
```

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def post_user_created_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(post_user_created_signal, sender=User)
```

Comment: You should check `user` (which is the result of `authenticate`) and not `request.user`, so `if user.is_superuser:`

Comment: Worked well, thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me why you make a `UserProfile` and create a custom user model at the same time. Usually one creates a `UserProfile` model to store the extra data **or** creates a custom user model where it can save the data, but not both.

Comment: I created it because I thought the above-mentioned problem owing to the custom user model... Userprofile was just test purposes